# sql How to hide row if entire row value is 0

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum, pivot

My Query :

```
SELECT 
    (ref_intake.intakeno) AS intake,
    SUM(CASE WHEN(student.intakeid AND student.status = '3' AND (student.courseid=3 OR student.courseid=17)) THEN 1 else 0 END) as active,
    SUM(CASE WHEN(student.intakeid AND student.status = '5' AND (student.courseid=3 OR student.courseid=17)) THEN 1 else 0 END) as deffered,
    SUM(CASE WHEN(student.intakeid AND student.status = '16' AND (student.courseid=3 OR student.courseid=17)) THEN 1 else 0 END) as inactive,
    SUM(CASE WHEN(student.intakeid AND student.status = '9' AND (student.courseid=3 OR student.courseid=17)) THEN 1 else 0 END) as missing,
    SUM(CASE WHEN(student.intakeid AND student.status = '6' AND (student.courseid=3 OR student.courseid=17)) THEN 1 else 0 END) as widthdrawn,
    SUM(CASE WHEN(student.intakeid AND student.status IN (18,7,36) AND (student.courseid=3 OR student.courseid=17)) THEN 1 else 0 END) as dis_ter_dereg
FROM student 
LEFT JOIN ref_intake ON student.intakeid = ref_intake.intakeid
GROUP BY student.intakeid ORDER BY ref_intake.intakeno ASC
```

The the image is  my result:

[image: reslut]

Comment: Wrap this query in main query and test.

Comment: can you provide sample data for both the tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do suspect that your query can be simplified as follows:

```
SELECT 
    s.intakeid AS intake,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.status = 3  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as active,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.status = 5  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as deffered,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.status = 16 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as inactive,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.status = 9  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as missing,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.status = 6  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as widthdrawn,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.status IN (18, 7, 36) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as dis_ter_dereg
FROM student s
INNER JOIN ref_intake ri ON  s.intakeid = ri.intakeid
WHERE
    s.intakeid 
    AND s.status IN (3, 5, 16, 9, 6, 18, 7, 36)
    AND s.courseid IN (3, 17)
GROUP BY s.intakeid 
ORDER BY ri.intakeno ASC
```

That is:

- most conditions can be moved to the `WHERE` clause - this should actually remove rows where no condition matches
- it seems like you actually want an `INNER JOIN` rather than a `LEFT JOIN` - but you can revert that change if needed
- table aliases make the query easier to read and write
- `OR`ed conditions can be simplified to use `IN`